# Селектор, выбирающий первые ячейки td

Tags: jquery

Как написать селектор Jquery, который выбирает первые ячейки `<td>` и при этом содержащие значение `index` из `<tr>`.

```
<tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>2</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>2</td><td>2</td></tr>
```

Надо выбрать первую ячеку (она уникальна в пределах первого столбца) в строках, содержащую 2, остальные ячейки не интересуют, id соответственно у ячеек нету. Мое предположение

```
$('[tr:first-child]:contains('+index+')')
```

не работает.

p.s. И вопрос про производительность: если имеется пятьсот строк в таблице, это сильно  скажется на длительности поиска?

Comment: Покажите разметку, что имено хотите выбирать! Смотря каким образом делается выборка.

Comment: Нужно выделить код мышью и нажать на кнопку 101010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#mytable tr').each(function(){
                var td=$(this).find('td:first').html();
                alert(td);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="mytable" border="1">
<tr><td>1-1</td><td>1-2</td><td>1-3</td></tr>
<tr><td>2-1</td><td>2-2</td><td>2-2</td></tr>
<tr><td>3-1</td><td>3-2</td><td>3-3</td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

вместо alert можете собрать все значения в массив и передать его куда надо, например php скрипту.

для сравнения значения из ячейки с вашим index используйте конструкцию:

```
if (!isNaN(td) && td==index){
     //do something
}
```

Comment: Все работает, Спасибо! Тоже пытался each использовать, но думал, что есть возможность все в один селектор уместить.

Comment: Нет это не для серверной стороны, а больше для удобства, так как записей много - использую jQuery.scrollTo для прокрутки до нужной ячейки.

Comment: ясн, тогда php ненадо точно. удачи с селекторами)